# MassTransit Consumer never invoked when using Windsor Integration

Tags: rabbitmq, castle-windsor, masstransit, consumer, topshelf

I can't seem to get the Castle Windsor Integration working for Mass Transit over RabbitMQ. Everything was working fine until I introduced Windsor into the picture. I referenced Castle.Windsor 3.2 and MassTransit.WindsorIntegration 2.9 and configured the container for use within my application. I'm registering the MassTransit Consumers via:

```
Container.Register(..., Types.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<IConsumer>());
```

When I debug and inspect the container after this line is ran, I can see that it successfully registered all of the consumers along with all of my other components. I then have the following code to initialize and register the service bus:

```
var serviceBus = ServiceBusFactory.New(sbc =>
{
    sbc.UseRabbitMq();
    sbc.ReceiveFrom(Config.ServiceBusEndpoint);
    sbc.Subscribe(sc => sc.LoadFrom(Container));
});

Container.Register(Component.For<IServiceBus>().Instance(serviceBus));
```

I am using the `LoadFrom(IWindsorContainer container)` extension method provided by MassTransit.WindsorIntegration.

All of the examples I've found so far stop here and indicate that this is all you should have to do. Unfortunately for me my Consumers are never being called and messages are just piling up in the queue (eventually timing out and going to error queue). The fact that messages are showing up in the Consumer queue at all (+ I see a single consumer bound to the queue via the RabbitMQ Admin Tool) indicates to me that the consumers are probably being subscribed properly - so I'm not sure where the problem lies.

I added NLog logging for Windsor and MassTransit but no errors are showing up in the logs. I'm not sure how I should proceed troubleshooting at this point. Any ideas?

Also, this application is currently just a console application using Topshelf for development.  Ultimately it will be installed as a Windows Service. Not sure if that is relevant or not but I thought I'd mention it just in case.

**UPDATE**

As a test I created a very simple Consumer with a parameter-less constructor for processing a very simple test message. This Consumer is successfully called! The "real" Consumers however have dependencies that need to be injected into them via the constructor. I was hoping the Container would resolve these but apparently it's having some sort of trouble. Weird that nothing is showing up in the logs about it. Stay tuned...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I figured it out. Somewhere along the way when I was adding/removing NuGet packages I somehow managed to delete a reference to a DLL (ServiceStack.Text.dll) that one of my components needed (RedisClientsManager).

I started the debugger, let all my components get registered then popped open the Immediate Window and attempted to resolve each component one by one (by calling container.Resolve<*RegisteredType*>()) until I found the one that threw the exception when I attempted to resolve it.

The Exception message from Windsor at that point told me exactly what the problem was. I'm a little lost as to why this wasn't being logged or why the Exception was not raised when the container itself attempted to resolve it. Anyhow, moral of the story is make sure your components resolve.